# Talend Open Studio Exiting

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, talend

I am using **Talend Open Studion for Data Integration v5.3.1** for Ubuntu. When I start the application, it is showing error in terminal. And after sometime, it is exiting. Its welcome page is not showing anything.

This is the whole error I am getting in Terminal

```
ERROR: The internal web browser can not be access,the starting page won't be displayed
java.lang.Exception: The internal web browser can not be access,the starting page won't be displayed
    at org.talend.rcp.intro.starting.StartingBrowser.createPartControl(StartingBrowser.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2860)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2674)
    at org.talend.rcp.intro.ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.showStarting(ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:297)
    at org.talend.rcp.intro.ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowOpen(ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.fireWindowOpened(WorkbenchWindow.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.open(WorkbenchWindow.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$66.runWithException(Workbench.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3515)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3515)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
>FULL BUILD STATS for: .Java
>   compiled 19746 lines in 2732ms:7227.6lines/s
>   parse: 473 ms (17.3%), resolve: 1498 ms (54.8%), analyze: 120 ms (4.3%), generate: 370 ms (13.5%)

***MEMORY-ERROR***: Talend Studio[2606]: GSlice: assertion failed: sinfo->n_allocated > 0
```

:/home/Talend/TOS_DI-r104014-V5.3.1$

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the source code of your XULRunner package and install it into /usr/local/lib.
Open TalendOpenStudio-linux-gtk-x86_64.ini and add the last line as below: for 64 bit machines

```
Code:

-vmargs
              -Xms40m
              -Xmx500m
              -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
              -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/local/lib/xulrunner
```

https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Exception+while+installing+Talend+Studio+on+a+Linux+system

Restart your machine